# When is the category of (quasi-coherent) sheaves of finite homological dimension?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let say from the beginning that my background is category of modules over a ring. 
So I know that if we take a given (nice) scheme $X$, then category of sheaves on $X$ is Grothendieck, so it must have enough injective, but it may fail to have projective. The question is then, when it is true that every object has an injective resolution with at most $n+1$ non zero terms ($n$ is fixed), or equivalently, when ${\rm\mathop Ext}^n(-,-)$ vanishes. If it possible, indicate please also a reference!

Comment: The question is too broad, even in the case that $X$ is affine.