# Categories of sheaves of finite homological dimension revisited

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

This is the question
[When is the category of (quasi-coherent) sheaves of finite homological dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344833/when-is-the-category-of-quasi-coherent-sheaves-of-finite-homological-dimension)
revisited.

I made some mistakes: I posted the question before I sign in, I tried to make it more explicit, but I cannot comment etc. So I reformulate it: are there relevant examples of non-affine schemes of finite homological dimension? Excuse me and tanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "relevant examples of non-affine schemes"? Would you consider regular, projective varieties over a field a good class of examples?

Comment: Yes, it is very well. Could you indicate also a reference?